# Optimal index for storing crypto addresses using bytea

Tags: postgresql, index, partitioning, bytea

I have a simple table that stores Ethereum addresses:

```sql
CREATE TABLE address (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    address bytea NOT NULL,
    attributes text[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::text[]
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX address_address_idx ON address(address bytea_ops);
```

The addresses are stored in a column using [bytea](/questions/tagged/bytea) type, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO address (address) VALUES (decode('0ef6F5fc97b1DC5601F858159e1C410Ae2306A47', 'hex'));
```

and they are looked up using:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT encode(address, 'hex')
FROM address
WHERE address = decode('78f294e4a5c73b0b6b230c2e4104e8852f16a3a4', 'hex');
```

which uses index as expected:

```sql
Index Only Scan using address_address_idx on address  (cost=0.42..2.65 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (address = '\x78f294e4a5c73b0b6b230c2e4104e8852f16a3a4'::bytea)
  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.103 ms
Execution Time: 0.026 ms
```

However, because of how often this query is called, it is among the top 3 most exec time taking queries (according `pg_stat_statements`).

What can I do to increase efficiency of lookup?

Comment: Why not simply store them say as strings and not go though the encoding and decoding? I don't see any **huge** gains there... Even a small query if it's being run many times will use resources...

Comment: If the concern here is the encoding speed, the encoding is done in the application, not database. I just send the buffer.

Comment: If you sort a non-empty list, something will always come out on top.  This does not indicate that there is a problem.  Is there a problem here to solve?  0.026ms does not seem to indicate one.